# Making the height of the right column the same as the left colum

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap, how can we make the height of two columns exactly the same?

For example:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
       Too much in here
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
       A little here resulting in shorter height 
   </div>
</div>
```

All I found through google or other posts asking the same thing here either did not work or if it did, it killed the responsiveness of bootstrap.

For example the `flex` technique works but it kills the responsive effect of bootstrap.

What is the proper and standard solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Comment: "kills the responsive effect of bootstrap" - how so? Bootstrap is responsive by default, even with flexbox enabled. Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @FreemanLambda: if you read the question fully you would not flag it!

Comment: @TiesonT.: no the flex makes the right column stick to the left one. So it does not move and shrink and go under the first column in a smaller screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: @Arrrr That hasn't been my experience. Perhaps it would be useful for you to amend your question to demonstrate that behavior?

Comment: @MTCoster: The answer in there did not help me.

Comment: @TiesonT.: It is exactly the case with the exact same code. After using the flex display, I was very happy I thought I made it but the result was disappointing as I described.

Comment: @Arrrr Perhaps check out this [link](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/different-tricks-on-how-to-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height) it shows you ways you can do this without using flex

Comment: @Matthew: It's taking about a JS solution, I'm a backend developer, I'm just looking for an easy CSS solution. Don't wanna complicate the UI.

Comment: @Arrrr there are many different solutions listed in that question. Why doesn't any of them work for you? Have you been able to nail down the reasons? Maybe one of the approaches there is very close to the solution you need. If you create a runable example of the problem we might be able to find it.

Comment: @FreemanLambda: Well, CSS is so, you may not believe me but I tried all of them. Only flux worked but with the downside that I described.

Comment: Well, since the parent does not have any height specified, I don't think it is even possible.

Comment: @Arrrr see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/codemonkeyco/pen/KmjYaR) could you please fix this to show your problem? I am not seeing an issue with what I have been given to work with.

Comment: @Matthew: That's awesome and it is what I want, but for me it doesn't work.

Comment: @Arrrr you are not guiding us to your problem. We have no idea of your situation. You really need to show us a recreation of your problem for us to help you.

Comment: I am using the default bootstrap/jquery CDN's here and nothing else. Could you include a full version of the html and css in a snippet to show your problem? We cannot help otherwise.

Comment: @Matthew: You used `Container` but here I have `Container-Fluid`, I think that's the issue

Comment: @Arrrr That does not matter as you can see [here](https://codepen.io/codemonkeyco/pen/KmjYaR). There is some other CSS or JavaScript that is overwriting the default bootstrap styles. Unless you show us your actual code/working example. We have no idea what needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Matthew: You are right, I understand what you are taking about

Comment: @Matthew: Thank you very very much indeed, using your codepen example, I could trace and solve the problem. The problem was the a dive inside of the column could not inherit the height. :)

Comment: @Arrrr Awesome I am glad I could help resolve the issue!